# How to set minimum size for m_wndClientArea in CMDIFramewndEx?

Tags: mfc, mfc-feature-pack

This is visualstudio screen.
[image: image1]

When resizing visualstudio screen to minimum, the tabbeddocument view, left and right dialogpane are displayed with some minimum size.
[image: image2]

After resizing IF I resize the screen to maximum by dragging it becomes like this.
[image: image3]

Whereas in my application which is a MDI tabbed group application created using MFC feature pack.
[image: image4]

When resizng to minimum the tabbed docuemnt and rightside pane is resized tozero width.For right pane I set the minimum size as  100 using SetMinSize().
[image: image5]

After resizing IF I resize the screen to maximum by dragging it , the right pane is not getting displayed.
[image: image6]

I guess, to achieve this  we need to set minimum size for CMDIFramewndEx's m_wndClientArea or CDockingManager's m_rectClientAreaBounds.

How to achieve this?

If you have any other solution please suggest me.

Thanks

Comment: We don't know what a `CMFCFramewndEx` is, or `m_wndClientArea`. More diligence required, and a clear problem statement.

Comment: Please elaborate, maybe with a picture. As it stands here your question is unclear.

Comment: Please don't post _pictures_ of your code, but post the code.

Answer (score 1):

In order to constraint the minimum size for an window, you have to handle WM_GETMINMAXINFO message:
in header:

```
afx_msg void OnGetMinMaxInfo(MINMAXINFO FAR* lpMMI);
```

and in cpp:

```
ON_WM_GETMINMAXINFO()

void CChildFrame::OnGetMinMaxInfo(MINMAXINFO FAR* lpMMI) 
{
// TODO: Add your message handler code here and/or call default

lpMMI->ptMinTrackSize.x = 100;
lpMMI->ptMinTrackSize.y = 200;

CMDIChildWnd::OnGetMinMaxInfo(lpMMI);
}
```

Comment: Hi flaviu2, Thanks for the reply. I have already tried your solution.It is working in cascade mode only.My application is having MDItabbedGroups with dockablepanes on left and right side so this solution is not working.

Comment: Why would you call the base class implementation anyway? Have a look at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/49a832ee-bc34-4126-88b3-bc1d9974f6c4.aspx#cwnd__ongetminmaxinfo).

Comment: Hi IInspectable,Yes.For application window the framework sets some minimum width but If I resize dockablepanes and tabbedgrouparea, it allows zero width also.

Comment: For dockablepane I am able to set minimum width by overriding OnGetMinMaxInfo in CDockablePane derived class but for tabbedgrouparea I dont know how to set minimum width

Comment: A possible workaround is o limit sizing of CMainFrame in order to not narrow at all the right pane ...

Comment: Flavviu2, Thanks for the reply.My superior does not accept your workaround.Is there any other way?

Comment: After the main window is resized, you can simply check if your pane are visible, if not make it visible: if(! m_wndPane.IsVisible)m_wndPane.ShowPane(! m_wndPane.IsVisible(), TRUE, TRUE);

Comment: More over, even this pane is visible, check his size, and if are below minimal accepted, do yourself as you need.

Comment: Hi flaviu2, As you said I added following code in Cmainframe's OnSize () function.if(m_wndObjBar.m_hWnd != NULL ){CRect rect;m_wndObjBar.GetWindowRect(&rect);ScreenToClient(&rect)if(rect.Width()<300);m_wndObjBar.SetWindowPos(NULL,0,0,300,cy,SWP_NOMOVE|SWP_NOACTIVATE|SWP_NOZORDER);}} Here instead of hardcoding 300 in Setwindowpos, I want to set the dockablepane's width  which is  the value of it's width, before starting to resize the mainframe window.How to do it?